# React initialize state with or without constructor

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to react and I was just wondering that why do we use this.state in constructor function and only state without constructor function while initializing state.

lets say:

i have created a component with constructor, here i have to specify this.state to intialize state.

```
    class Test {

   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
       name : ""
   }

     }

   }
```

and if i create a component without constructor , i can use only state to initialize state:

```
 class Test{
   state = {
      name : ""
   }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what you're referring to in particular?

Comment: Yes a snippet will help

Comment: I have added the snippet into the original question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize state like the below or can use React Hooks

import React from 'react';

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: 'hello world',
  };

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;
    return <h1>{title}</h1>;
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

with Hook, you can initialize a state like the below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('hello world');

  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: It's not that how to intialize state, I am asking why do we use this.state in constructor function where as only state without constructor function?